# Can android studio create "#" to collect data like "twitter"?

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I mean like **twitter search bar** can we use **"#"** to search ?

user create post and put **"#"** in post, when i'm new user i don't know what other user posted.

and I want to want to search with **"#"** is it possible ?

**[search like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdUdO.png)**
and create post put **"#"** inside post like this **[inside post like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJaDQ.png)**

**I don't know what is call sorry for making confuse and waste time.**

**Best regards**

Comment: 'Android Studio' is an IDE tool and that tag should be use for problems with the tool directly rather than what you can do with the tool. Your question is too broad and StackOverflow works best with specific programming problem, generally showing your  research and/or code and errors.

Comment: @Morrison Chang my question mean like twitter in search bar. when you want to search something it will use hashtag to search it. sorry for question is too broad. I don't know what is that call.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what the problem is. Can you please be more specific?

Comment: im very sorry for making confused and waste time. i edited and i don't know this time it a specific or not.